# Ansible create variable depending on condition

Tags: ansible

I want to create a variable depending on the distribution, the following code does not work and i dont know why:

```
- name: Get Release
  vars: release: xenial
  when: (ansible_distribution_release == 'qiana') or 
        (ansible_distribution_release == 'rebecca') or 
        (ansible_distribution_release == 'rafaela') or 
        (ansible_distribution_release == 'rosa')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the following code does not work and i dont know why

Because there is no module named `vars`.

You can do this with the [set_fact module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/set_fact_module.html):

```
- name: Get Release
  set_fact:
    release: xenial
  when: (ansible_distribution_release == 'qiana') or 
        (ansible_distribution_release == 'rebecca') or 
        (ansible_distribution_release == 'rafaela') or 
        (ansible_distribution_release == 'rosa')
```

Comment: For the sake of beauty I'd use: `when: ansible_distribution_release in ['qiana', 'rebecca', 'rafaela', 'rosa']`